# Cannot get a Cron event to fire on my Linux server

Tags: php, linux, shell, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a Amazon EC2 Linux micro instance server that I need to fire an hourly process on. I have chosen to use crontab and cannot get it to fire.

I placed a *.sh file in the /etc/cron.hourly

- If I run `$ sh /etc/cron.hourly/notify.sh` the script behaves as expected.
- I have checked to see if the cron service is running and it is.
- I have checked `crontab` contents are at the end

notify.php logs when it is called so I can tell that the service is never running. 
Any ideas?

Thanks

### contents of: /etc/cron.hourly/notify.sh

```
curl localhost/notify.php
```

### contents of: /etc/crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash  
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin  
MAILTO=root   HOME=/       

# run-parts  
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly  
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily  
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly  
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Comment: Does the script have the executable bit set? Also, you may want to add a shebang (#!/bin/bash) line at the top.

Comment: cron does have logs you can check as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this line to `/etc/crontab`

```
* * * * * root curl /etc/notify.sh >>/var/log/cron.log
```

This created output ever minute that helped me track down the issue. In the end I had a typo in the script.

Thanks for everyone's help!!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to check the file permissions. x-bit should be set. Another thing is #!/bin/sh in the first line of your script. Last one probably isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the environment might differ; try something like **/bin/echo hello world** (use *which* to find their *echo*). If that works, it's probably a $PATH problem.